# slow elasticsearch query when using terms_set query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I need to query a specific field in an index and find an exact match for at least one word in that field.

The index contains 2.5M documents and each query takes ~10 seconds.
I'm trying to find a way to make the query faster. according to the search profiler most of the time is spent in the create_weight phase.

any help will be appreciated.

This is the index definition:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 3,
      "number_of_replicas": 2
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "sentence": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is an example of how a document looks like:

```
 { "sentence" : [
            "FZC","XFN","KNP","YST","HCX","QAK","SGD","PPP","SSP","PBO","RQD","BEW","SGP","YVM", "XPD", "WTU", "ZHW", "XMZ", "OPD", "LMX", "ZGW", "XLE", "YIX", "RTD", "QMR", "WHL", "JJH", "SGI", "SVI"         
          ],
          "name" : "ID_1",
          "required_matches" : 1
}
```

and this is the query I'm running:

````
{
  "query": {
    "terms_set": {
      "sentence": {
        "terms": ["FZC", "KNP", "YST", "SGD", "SSP", "PBO", "RQD", "MMS", "ELY", "GPP", "XWX", "OKQ", "LKH", "ANQ", "FVA", "IBN", "JDC", "JQM", "JTX", "GOJ", "RUU", "BCQ", "UST", "IBG", "CSY", "QAV", "LWS", "WDN", "UOT", "HAJ", "WRD", "YEI", "ZFH", "NDX", "VYA", "RSV", "GVU", "GPO", "JBI", "SUS", "BCV", "FSZ", "FGQ", "EDM", "AYI", "VZD", "BBY", "MLB", "VMI", "NEY", "IBS", "UEU", "HZE", "RJT", "KYA", "LXE", "PEO", "DKO", "ATT", "WGT", "UBV", "AFO", "VRI", "MAS", "YVM", "XPD", "WTU", "ZHW", "XMZ", "OPD", "LMX", "ZGW", "XLE", "YIX", "RTD", "QMR", "WHL", "JJH", "SGI", "SVI", "YRR", "ZNE", "YHF", "XDD", "ZKR", "JZY", "ELD", "CCU", "NPT", "UMA", "OEI", "XXV", "WOV", "STJ", "ZZM", "HQE", "IED", "KDZ", "GPX", "XUW", "XMR", "GGM", "HUC", "XUA", "DRQ", "OAY", "SBW", "FQO", "OTV", "ULB", "BRN", "KGB", "ILT", "NOP", "XGK", "OAA", "DWE", "CZJ", "HVT", "QPH", "XQY", "ZUK", "RGS", "YHG", "TOJ", "JLZ", "VMI", "PRX", "CXG", "YLJ", "CWE", "BET", "FKZ", "FJC", "BCC", "XRY", "QGM", "EPX", "ZJE", "VIO", "XAJ", "YQS", "RDD", "SCF", "KTH", "FPR", "DHK", "PFG", "MBL", "BJT", "DBN", "BWX", "UIF", "SPS", "JFT", "XUK", "ZQO", "CLL", "RJL", "LYB", "LFT", "WDD", "OYI", "XAP", "PEH", "PIQ", "SLB", "NWZ", "YHJ", "DDR", "SOF", "EHI", "QWG", "RHK", "QVO", "UUI", "CJK", "QRA", "DTV", "VFE", "FAP", "GVB", "NFY", "QNP", "FDH", "URK", "RZE", "ABB", "SOF", "IUQ", "ICJ", "HSA", "FJU", "TCM", "KDJ", "XRF", "LBG", "QSU", "TWM", "UZC", "WAR", "EBP", "FYS", "RUG", "NWV", "NHY", "UXZ", "QRB", "NER", "WSU", "JVU", "SIP", "IJU", "KVS", "TPT", "AQU", "GOF", "XDF", "LMJ", "TTA", "BBS", "PRN", "KMY", "WCY", "ZCU", "RGI", "ALR", "MBM", "DZX", "KJU", "TBZ", "HMG", "KKL", "ZKW", "AVJ", "WNX"],
        "minimum_should_match_field": "required_matches"
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Could it be related to the network? Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Normally the expectation of term query should be as fast as enough.